# {Unity} effect other objects after collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game with unity and I have a question.

I have 5 game objects + player. And they always rotate when the game has started. I want that if the player collides with the object that is tagged snowflake, the other 4 objects pause the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a static event on your player script, when player collide invoke that event. On other scripts subscribe to that event.

For example in your PlayerScript should be something like

```
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public static UnityAction OnPlayerCollidedWithSnowFlakes;

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) {
        if (other.gameObject.tag.Equals("snowflake")) {
            OnPlayerCollidedWithSnowFlakes?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

And your RotatingObjectScript should be something like

```
public class RotatingObjectScript : MonoBehaviour {
    private void Awake() {
        PlayerScript.OnPlayerCollidedWithSnowFlakes += CollidedWithSnowflakeEventHandler;
    }

    private void OnDestroy() {
        PlayerScript.OnPlayerCollidedWithSnowFlakes -= CollidedWithSnowflakeEventHandler;
    }

    private void CollidedWithSnowflakeEventHandler() {
        .
        .
        // Stop rotating
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for your answer, I have another question, what is the PlayerScript I couldn't understand that part? is it the name of the player or something like that?

Comment: PlayerScript is a script you need to attach on your player object

Comment: Member 'playerrotatescript.OnPlayerCollidedWithSnowFlakes' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

The error like this

Comment: Seems like you are tring to access the event with instance variable, just use the Class name or your script name

Comment: when i use the class or script name I need the reference the object, but I have too much in that object. or u talking about another thing? because I am new at gem developing